# Populating drop down using Ajax too slow

Tags: jquery, ajax

This question has been asked in the forum, but the fastest solution ever suggested too was taking too much time for me.

I am loading a java `List` from servlet into a drop down list using ajax. I parse the `List` as a json object. The List contains around 130 - 150 elements. The jQuery code takes about 9 seconds to populate the json into the drop down list. I checked the time taken to get response from server and it just takes 2 seconds only. The rest of the time is taken to populate drop down. How can I reduce this time? Thanks in advance.

Browser used : IE 7

Declaration of java `List` I used

```
ArrayList <Country> countryList = new  ArrayList <Country>();

Class Country {
    String code;
    String name;
    String xxxxxx;
    String llllll;
    int yyyyyyyyy;
    int zzzzzzzzzz;
    int mmmmmmmmmmm;
}
```

AJAX code (This is not the same code, but approach is exactly same)

```
$.ajax({
    url: "../Controller",
    type: "POST",
    async:false,
    dataType:"json",
    data:{"cntry":dat},
    success : function (jsonDatas) {
       var listOption = "";
       $.each(jsonDatas, function(index, jsonValue) {
           listOption = listOption
                      + "<option value = '"
                      + jsonValue.code+"'>"
                      + jsonValue.name
                      +"</option>";
        });

       $("#country").empty();
       $("#country").html(listOption);
    }
});
```

Comment: You will have to provide a demo of that. Maybe your Container is slow, maybe the Query is not efficient or maybe a dinosaur is gnawing on your internet connection... Have you tried to call your controller without ajax? Is that as fast as expected?

Comment: Why are you loading such a list from the server? Isn't it a static list?

Comment: I checked time taken to get response from server using Chrome network analyzing tool as part of dev tool. It is less than 2 sec.The country list is fetched from data base and its content varies depending on some other factrors, that is why I had to use list insted of array